# DFP errors on swf file - "Flash files with mouse tracking are not allowed."

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, google-dfp

I built a flash project that uses the Jumpeye Components.  I exported to an .swf file and I'm getting an error when uploading my creative to Doubleclick For Publishers.

"Flash files with mouse tracking are not allowed."

What might be causing this, or how can I disable mouse tracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to setup the banner as a "3rd party" banner ad and it's working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably they check if the SWF you upload listens for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` while inactive (by default). So, if your Jumpeye component is an eye following your mouse cursor, as I guess by the name, it does this very trick, is detected and disallowed.

Comment: It's just a series of animation effects to use inside flash - I'm not doing any mouse tracking.  Is there a way to explicitly disable this during publish?

Comment: I don't get the restrictions from their site. Maybe ask their support of what this means? Make sure though that there's no `addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, anything)` in your code or code of those components.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass this, when uploading the creative, select "system defined templates" then type in "Flash banner with optional third party tracking".

All of the standard Flash fields are available.

Not sure if this is what the accepted answer means, but that wasn't apparent.